# Proper way to do bitwise difference? (python 2.7)

Tags: python, set, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am storing sets of values as python long integers, in the form of distinct 2**i sums, because python allows bitwise operations on it's integers.  For many of my programs this is much faster than using data structures.

I often find myself wanting to take the difference of two bitwise values.

Example:

Let's say I have two values, represented by 2 and 4.  By union they form a set, the value 6. (110)
I then have a second set, decimal value 10(binary 1010), which is 2 and 8.

I want to find the value that is in the first set, and not in the second set.  If I was using set structures, I would take set difference.  But I am using integers.  If I  try to do difference, it won't work (it would be -4).

As of now, I find myself doing value1 - (value1&value2).  This requires two separate operations to find the difference.  Is there a way I can take advantage of what python offers to quickly do this in one operation instead of two?

Comment: If you find dealing with bits directly complicated, you may want to use a third-party library like `bitset` or `bitsets` or… there seem to be a few of them on PyPI, so search and look over all of them. But anyway, they'll give you an object that acts like a set of bits, with normal set operations,, but is represented by one big integer (and can be converted to/from an integer).

Comment: expected value would be 4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set difference `B-A` is just the intersection of `B` and the complement of `A`.

And, while there's no bitwise difference operator, there are bitwise intersection (`&`) and bitwise complement (`~`) operators. So:

```
b_minus_a = b & ~a
```

Or, using your example:

```
>>> b, a = 0b110, 0b1010
>>> b & ~a
4
>>> bin(_)
0b100
```

---

You can of course wrap this up in a function:

```
def bitsetdiff(b, a):
    return b & ~a
```

---

But if you're going to be doing a lot of this kind of stuff, and bitwise operations don't come naturally to you, you may want to search PyPI for libraries for [bit set](https://pypi.org/search/?q=bit+set) and [bitset](https://pypi.org/search/?q=bitset), which will give you an object that acts like a set of boolean values, but is stored as (and can be efficiently converted to and from) an integer.

I chose [`intbitset`](https://pypi.org/project/intbitset/) because it looks promising:

```
>>> b = intbitset([2, 4])
>>> a = intbitset([2, 8])
>>> b - a
intbitset([4])
```

Just like using sets. But I don't see any obvious way to access the value as one big integer. There might be other libraries that fit your needs better; I only picked one after a quick scan.

Comment: I had this (in a now-deleted answer), but it's also two operations.

Comment: im just glad to know for certain that there's no way to do it in a single operation (or if there was, it would be a facade :P).  I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @wim If you define a function, calling that function is just one operation as far as your code goes. And if you use a bit set library, you can literally write `b - a` instead of `bitsetdiff(b, a)`. Of course under the covers it's doing more than one bitwise operation, but under the covers even `a & b` is doing more than one bitwise operation—it's looking up and calling a special method which is ultimately implemented as an equivalent of a mapping a bitwise operation over the zip of the digits underlying the `int` objects and building a new `int` object…

Answer (score 5):

Not in one operation, but you should stick to bit operations (not `+` or `-`).  If you want the bits in `value1` not in `value2`, the ordinary way to spell that is

```
value1 & ~value2
```

That is, the intersection of `value1` with the complement of `value2` (note that the unary prefix operator there is `~`, not `-`).